# Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class while extending Task class

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm trying to extend Task class, but I get two different errors depending how I extend it:
first one:

```
public class ExtTask : Task
{
    public static void DoSomenthing(this Task task)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

so I add static:

```
public static class ExtTask : Task
{
    public static void DoSomenthing(this Task task)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

getting error:

> Static class 'DownloadFile.ExtTask' cannot derive from type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'. Static classes must derive from object.

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You're trying to derive from task, which is unnecessary (and impossible with a static class). Drop the inheritance and keep the class static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to derive from task if you are trying to add an extension method, change it to

```
public static class ExtTask
{
    public static void DoSomenthing(this Task task)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```